# Dojo TabContainer sizing

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabcontainer

I'm currently using a TabContainer containing several ContentPanes in dojo. The content is generated during page generation, and does not change after that. Is there any way to force certain tabs to resize the TabContainer to prevent the user from having to use the scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to [set the doLayout property to false](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#a-tabcontainer-with-flexible-height)?